# Remove the "^M" at the and of each line when its doesnt match Perl

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

How can i remove the "^M" at the and of each line when its doesnt match ? the command is:

```
perl -pe 's{(">)[^</zone>]}{$1</zone>}g' $travail_dir/zones.txt >$travail_dir/ys.txt
```

i get this in my ys.txt :

```
<zone^M
numero_page="005"></zone>^M
<zone^M
id_zone="2"^M
numero_page="005"></zone>
```

How can i modify my command to get the expected result without "^M" ?

Comment: `[^</zone>]` is just wrong, did you mean `(">)(?!</zone>)`? Try `perl -pe 's/\r//g;s{(">)(?!</zone>)}{$1</zone>}g'`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew yes you're right, you saved me, thx

Comment: [Why is it such a bad idea to parse XML with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1030675)

Comment: @choroba It is true that parsing valid XML with regex is a bad idea, but here, the XML is invalid and OP tries to make it valid to make it parsable.

Comment: Perhaps you got the file from MS Windows and you utilize it in Linux. Windows and Unix have different end of line. You can make required changes with editor [vim](https://www.vim.org/) which in most cases installed. Open file with editor `vim filename`, in editor issue a command `:set ff=unix` and save file `:wq`. Or if in your system available utility `dos2unix` you can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things here:

- `[^</zone>]` matches any single char other than `<`, `/`, `z`, `o`, `n`, `e` and `>`, it does not mean *any text other than `</zone>`. You need to use a negative lookahead here, `(?!</zone>)` that will fail the `">` match if it is directly followed with `</zone>`
- `^M` are *carriage returns*, CR symbols, and you may either remove them with `dos2unix` before passing the file to `perl`, or just remove them with a separate substitution command, `s/\r//g`.

You can use

```
perl -pe 's/\r//g;s{(">)(?!</zone>)}{$1</zone>}g' $travail_dir/zones.txt > $travail_dir/ys.txt
```